# Existence theorem for the SIR epidemic differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Well these days, everybody is talking about the epidemic model SIR
which is given by the following differential equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
S'(t)=-aS(t)I(t)\\
I'(t)=aS(t)I(t)-bI(t)\\
R'(t)=bI(t)\\
S(0)>0,I(0)>0
\end{cases}
$$

We can see that $S'(t)+I'(t)+R'(t)=0$, so $S(t)+I(t)+R(t)=N$ is
a constant. Thus this model reduces to two differential equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
S'(t)=-aS(t)I(t)\\
I'(t)=aS(t)I(t)-bI(t)\\
S(0)>0,I(0)>0
\end{cases}
$$

All the studies I saw start with the fact that a solution of this
model is global (defined on $[0,\infty)$) and positive. So I wanted
to prove that this differential equation has a global solution. However
I see that this cannot be done by the global Lipschitz Picard-Lindelöf/contraction
theorem, since the function
$$
f(x,y)=\left(-axy,axy-by\right)
$$
 is not globally Lipschitz. How can we prove the existence of a global
solution and its positivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, $S+I+R=N$ is constant.
We assume we begin with $S, I, R \ge 0$, since negative populations are not of interest.  Moreover the constants $a, b \ge 0$.  To show global existence, we just need to show that the solution stays in the compact set $D = \{(s,i,r): s+i+r=N, s \ge 0, i \ge 0, r \ge 0\}$.  But $R' \ge 0$ while $S' \ge - aN S$ and $I' \le -b I$ when $(S,I,R) \in D$, which implies $S$ and $I$ never reach $0$.

Comment: Just to make this more clear for OP, this proves existence because of results concerning the maximal interval of existence for IVPs. In particular, if a solution $x$ to an IVP is only defined on $(-\infty,T]$, then $\lim_{t\to T} |x(t)|\to\infty$, so a solution staying in a compact set implies that $T=\infty$ so solutions are global

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to prove the positivity, that is: $S(0)>0,I(0)>0$
and $R(0)=0$ implies that $S(t)>0$ and $I(t)>0$ for all $t\geq0$ ?

Comment: If $S' > - a N S$, i.e. $\dfrac{d}{dt} \ln S > - a N$, then $\ln(S(t)) > \ln(S(0)) - a N t$ and $S(t) > S(0) e^{-aNt}$.